# How to make sure a single Runnable task isn't running simultaneously on two threads

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice

For e.g. if I have a thread pool of two threads, but want each thread to be dedicated to a single type of task. i.e. task 1 can only execute on thread 1 of the pool , task 2 on thread 2 of the pool. I dont want more than two threads and I dont want two task1(s) to run simultaneously (one on each thread). Possible??

Comment: Why does it matter which thread is used in the pool?

Comment: it doesnt matter which thread would be used in the pool to service which task. Just that two task1 should not be running simultaneously. Also I have no control on the order of tasks coming in. Any ideas on how to get it to work? I only should have two threads active at a time.No more.

Comment: Then create a `boolean` for each task, specifying whether it's running or not. Both tasks should first check if it's already running (check the boolean). If not, set the boolean to true and continue. If your task is already running and it's executed again, itll exit since the boolean is true (its already running). Ensure the task only exexutes if its not already running

Comment: Your question's title assumes a task needs to run on a specific thread. The problem is that you actually wanna ensure one task is not running on two threads. If Luiggi's answer or my comment didn't satisfy you, I suggest editing the title

Comment: Thanks Vince. I appreciate your response and it works for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you wanna make sure a single task isn't being executed twice at the same time, use a `boolean` to specify whether that task is running or not:

(Java 8+)

```
volatile boolean task1Running = false;

Runnable task1 = () -> {
     if(task1Running)
          return; //already running, exit

     task1Running = true;
     //handle task
     task1Running = false;
};
```

Now when you try to execute it while it's already running, it'll exit. `volatile` is to ensure that when we change `task1Running` from the Thread managing the task, all other threads (specifically, the thread that executes the tasks) will see it right away.

Comment: I should perhaps mention that `volatile` does not help here since it is still possible that two threads read the unmodified variable to decide if they should return early, so if they see it as false, they proceed, setting it to true first and later to false. There is a short time between reading task1Runnig and writing. They only way to avoid this is an atomic CompareAndSet as provided by AtomicBoolean. This will eliminate the short gap between test and set.
Volatile only gurantees that reading task1Running happens after any write. It does not close the time gap.

Comment: @RalfH "*Reads and writes are atomic for all variables declared volatile*" - [Atomic Access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) Mind removing the downvote?

Comment: Please read my comment again. Of course, the first read of `task1Running` is atomic, meaning the whole variable is fetched from memory in one operation. Same for any write. The link regarding atomic access is for reads and writes from memory. On some architectures, reads/writes for 64bit values may be split into two memory acesses and yield undefined results for the time between those two accesses. This is not the issue here.

Answer (score 2):

No, not possible. That's the benefit of using a thread pool: the pool will choose which thread will execute the delivered task. Note that even if you use [`Executors#newFixedThreadPool(2)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-), you will have a thread pool with 2 threads, but this doesn't guarantee that each task is executed in a different thread.

If you need your tasks to be executed in different particular threads, then create your own threads instead. In case you don't want to manually create the threads, then use 2 single threaded executors. You can create them by using [`Executors#newSingleThreadExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor--) (but this is very cumbersome).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Thats what I am doing currently. Was hoping there would be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Although there already is an accepted answer, you must use an `AtomicBoolean` instead of a `volatile`.
Like in

```
AtomicBoolean task1RunningAB = new AtomicBoolean( false);

Runnable task1 = () -> {
    // compareAndSet( E, N) sets the value to N if current value matches E. 
    // Returns true if that was the case, so we must negate here
    if ( ! task1RunningAB.compareAndSet( false, true))
         return; 
    try {
        // your code
    } finally {
        task1RunningAB.set( false);
    }
};
```